# Adding dataframes to List in Spark

Tags: sql, scala, list, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm trying to create "n" `dataframes` based on the data of one. I'm checking the Integer value of a `column` in `dataframe` and looping the sql sentence for creating "n" `dataframes` as many as `Integers` in the column.

This is my code:

```
val maxvalue = spark.sql("SELECT MAX(column4) as maxval FROM mydata").collect()(0).getInt(0)
for( i <- 0 to maxvalue){
         var query = "SELECT column1,colum2,colum3 FROM mydata WHERE column4 = "+ i
         val newdataframe = spark.sql(query)
         //add dataframe to List

}
```

I need to create "n" `dataframes` but I don't know how to declare the `List` type before loop and populate inside the for.

The existing `dataframe` data type:

```
// +------------+------------+------------+------------+
// |     column1|     column2|     column3|     column4|
// +------------+------------+------------+------------+
// |      String|      Double|         Int|         Int|
// +------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

The new `dataframes` data type:

```
// +------------+------------+------------+
// |     column1|     column2|     column3|     
// +------------+------------+------------+
// |      String|      Double|         Int|
// +------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: please add example data, as of now  your code is not reproducible.

Comment: I've added the dataframe data type

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a mutable list and populate it:

```
val dfs = mutable.ArrayBuffer[DataFrame]()
for( i <- 0 to maxvalue){
  val query = "SELECT column1,colum2,colum3 FROM mydata WHERE column4 = "+ i
  val newdataframe = spark.sql(query)
  dfs += newdataframe
}
```

But a better approach (not using mutable data structure) is to *map* the list of integers into a list of DataFrames:

```
val dfs: Seq[DataFrame] = (0 to maxvalue).map { i => 
  spark.sql("SELECT column1,colum2,colum3 FROM mydata WHERE column4 = " + i)
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you very much. I've use the second aproach. The better one. ;)

Comment: mutable does not work with databricks notebook for 1st option. any idea why?

Comment: Don't ask me why, but all of a sudden the second option works.