# List of data frames in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

Is it advisable to create a list of dataframes in Spark?

```
List<Dataset<Row>> list = some method
```

Method  reads  x Number of files to create x dataframes  from it. These dataframes are pushed to the list.

This method is getting called from the driver program and returns a single data frame created by joining the dataset in the list.

I am confused as to where will the list be formed, on the driver node or the worker nodes?

Is it advisable to create a list of dataframes?

Comment: union I suspect as opposed to join.

Comment: No it’s a join operation on the dataframes in the list

Comment: Odd to say the least.

Comment: It’s the requirement of the use case .  Actually the input files vary in number from source to source , n The idea is to write a generic code that would read  these files to create separate data frames for each file n then join them based on some conditions

Comment: A Scala example can be founded in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956153/adding-dataframes-to-list-in-spark

Comment: Sounds like a dimensional approach here?

Answer (score 0):

List is on driver. Each entry points to a DF that is distributed or on driver when the Action is executed. How else could it be?

Difficult to comment if list of DFs is good or bad.

Comment: I can tell u one more thing , we are not calling any actions or collecting any data till all the dataframes are joined , post join we are calling a save operation . Considering this scenario  now do u think it’s a good idea

Comment: No issuecwith that, that is normal in Spark.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind spark uses lazy execution and that dataframes are really just execution graphs and not data (unless you've cached the data).  In this case the list will be on the driver waiting for you todo an operation on the dataframes that forces them to be executed such as writing the data.

Are you trying to union all of these dataframes together?  Without knowing exactly what you're trying todo its generally better to keep the total number of dataframes to a reasonable number <1k as each dataframe is a new node in the execution graph that needs to be optimized.  Ultimately the what you're trying todo will decide if it's reasonable or not.

Comment: There are multiple sources which generate multiple parquet files . From these parquet files we are creating data frames  .  Now say 7 source have 7 files n I am creating 7 Dfs from them . All these 7 dogs I push inside a list  n then use this list to join all the 7 data frames to create one consolidated df .  Post the join I am performing some transformations on some columns n finally writing the Data to a parquet file . This output file then loads a snowflake table

Comment: * NOT 7 DOGS  but 7 dataframes :P

Comment: Why do u feel so ?

Comment: Dataframe an execution graph? There is a DAG. For sure. I am not convinced

Comment: @andrew long — when u say 1k what exactly do u mean by it ?